# Two (or multiple) GeoJSON Layers in angular leaflet directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, leaflet

How to add two or more GeoJson Layers to the map using [angular-leaflet-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive)?

I am able to draw features from one service (poly lines) using 'geojson' directive as shown in this [example](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/geojson-example.html).

But I have another GeoJson web service (circles) that I need to draw on the map in the same way I did the first one. Can you guide me please?

Is there an example for this? I looked but couldn't fine.

I also asked this question on [github issues](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/issues/355) for the project but haven't gotten any answer yet.

Just to be clear, the question is not about regular LeafletJS, but about the angular-leaflet-directive.

Comment: can you post some sample json from each service?  i'd like to experiment with this, without having to use $http

Comment: GeoJSON I am using is too long to post, but the question is more generic and not json specific.. You can use any two geojson you want to. Adding one is simple.. how to add second one is the question.. thanks..

Comment: understood.  just suggesting that if i had a small subset of data from each service i might be able to mock up a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to get around this problem by just opening up the map object inside the controller by injecting the lealfletData service and then:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('MyController', ['$scope', `leafletData`,
    function($scope, leafletData) {
            leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
               // do something with leaflet map object here.. 
            });
    }
]);
```

For reference look at the [Project's GitHub](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive#how-to-use-it), and under **How to Use** section look at 4th code example.

Comment: thanks for sharing, it is great. do you have any reference to any documentation for this?

Comment: now I can figure who to remove a geojson layer. do you have an idea by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add in multiple GeoJSON layers, but had to tweak the directive's code. It worked for my purpose. Please check if this works for your project as well.

I noticed that it always displayed only the last GeoJSON layer that was added. I debugged and found that it was removing the previous layer and then adding in the latest data. I have not dug in further and so have not submitted my mod to the repository yet because I have not verified as to what else the repercussions might be (i.e, why GeoJSON data are not maintained in there as a LayerGroup or an array of Layers).

I removed lines 438, 439, 440 in the file angular-leaflet-directive.js (Distribution: 0.7.6):

```
if (isDefined(leafletGeoJSON) && map.hasLayer(leafletGeoJSON)) {
     map.removeLayer(leafletGeoJSON);
}
```

That allowed me to have multiple Layers.

Comment: ah! that's a nice fix. I fixed it in my case by directly accessing map object inside the controller, like they show in one of the examples. +1 but I still want to look for a more elegant solution .

Answer (score 0):

My preference for this (without modifying the core library) was as follows:

- Create a new factory for handling GeoJSON in the map
- Setup a hash of layer IDs within this controller
- Allow assignment of style handling callbacks for each layer
- Implement an `addLayer` method which will add layer IDs to each geoJSON object passed in
- Add a single style handling callback which reads the layer ID of each feature and runs the appropriate style callback

A gist of the service code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/pospi/85c31530c4a93cf091ce

Comment: I might be wrong here.. but aren't you adding all features from different GeoJSON layer to same layer and managing styles?

Comment: Yup, exactly! (: It's not terribly fast when updating but managing it externally like this is the only way to do it (that I could find) if you don't want to hack at the core library.